# wpbd to connect to a VPS mysql database

Tags: php, database

I need to connect to a external database on my wordpress site but this database is on a VPS so I have the SSH Hostname, SSH username, SSH password, MySQL HostName on the VPS, MySQL port on the VPS, the Mysql username and the MySQL Password but the wpdb object just ask for the database host, password, table and user so where should be defined the vps authentication information? can I use mslqli extension to achieve the connection ? if so how can I install the extension on wordpress?

Comment: A couple of questions:

1. Are you trying to connect to a WordPress database on the server?  (WP_???) or are you trying to connect to a separate database to run with your plugin.
2. Is this a custom plugin that was written for you or a particular plugin you installed?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new [`wpdb`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) object, and then use that.

```
global $mydb;
$mydb = new wpdb( $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $db_host );
```

...and then use `$mydb` as you would the global `$wpdb` object.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but which will be the ```$db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $db_host ``` if i use the ones of the mysql database wont be connected because the vps dont have exposed this to the internet, just the ssh credentials so this won't work

Comment: You'd need the MySQL username and password. If you can't connect to the database over the internet, then WordPress can't connect to it (unless it's on the same VPS, I suppose).